Custom Input data type in data table and Inline editing
Custom datatype in LWC datatable, Customizing the Quantity field as a custom input data type and the Price field for inline editing.
When attempting to change the Quantity value, the value is captured, but I also need to capture the row/record ID and the field name. How can this be achieved?"
Also when I change price field both onchange and handleCellChange method is calling.
Below is code snippet
   ├──customInput.html
   ├──CustomTypeGlobal.html
   ├──CustomTypeGlobal.js
   └──CustomTypeGlobal.js-meta.xml

customInput.html
<template>
    <lightning-input name="quantity" type="number" value={typeAttributes.value} onchange={typeAttributes.methodquantity}
        variant="label-hidden" class="slds-input" data-id={rowId}></lightning-input>
</template>

CustomTypeGlobal.html
<template>

</template>

CustomTypeGlobal.js
import LightningDatatable from 'lightning/datatable';
import customInput from './customInput.html'

export default class CustomTypeGlobal extends LightningDatatable {

    static customTypes = {
        quantityInput: {
            template: customInput,
            standardCellLayout: true,
            typeAttributes: ['label', 'value', 'methodquantity'],
        }
    }
}

accountDatatable.js
// accountDatatable.js
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import getAccounts from '@salesforce/apex/AccountController.getAccounts';

const columns = [
    { label: 'Account Name', fieldName: 'Name' },
    { label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'Phone' },
    { label: 'Industry', fieldName: 'Industry' },
    {
        label: 'Quantity', hideDefaultActions: true, type: 'quantityInput',
        typeAttributes: {
            value: { fieldName: 'Quantity_one__c' },
            recid: { fieldName: 'Id' },
            methodquantity: { fieldName: 'methodquantity' }
        }
    },
    { label: 'Price', fieldName: 'Price__c', editable: true }
];

export default class AccountDatatable extends LightningElement {
    @track data = [];
    @track error;
    columns = columns;

    connectedCallback() {
        this.fetchAccounts();
    }

    fetchAccounts() {
        getAccounts()
            .then(result => {
                this.data = result;
                this.error = undefined;
                console.log(' this.data -->' + JSON.stringify(this.data));
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.error = error;
                this.data = undefined;
            });
    }

    handleCellChange(event) {
        console.log('handleCellChange -->' + event.detail);
        
    }

    handleSave() {
        // Collect the draft values from the datatable
        const draftValues = this.template.querySelector('lightning-datatable').draftValues;
        if (draftValues.length > 0) {
        }
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        console.log('Value -->' + event.detail.value);
        console.log('event.detail -->' + JSON.stringify(event.detail));
    }
}

accountDatatable.html
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Account List">
        <!-- <lightning-datatable key-field="Id" data={data} columns={columns} hide-checkbox-column="true"
            oncellchange={handleCellChange} draft-values={draftValues}>
        </lightning-datatable> -->

        <c-custom-type-global key-field="Id" data={data} columns={columns} hide-checkbox-column="true"
            oncellchange={handleCellChange} draft-values={draftValues} onchange={handleChange}>
        </c-custom-type-global>
    </lightning-card>
    <lightning-button label="Save" onclick={handleSave} class="slds-m-top_medium">
    </lightning-button>
</template>


To get the row/record ID and the field name when changing the quantity value, you need to modify your customInput.html and accountDatatable.js files as follows:
customInput.html
<template>
        <lightning-input name="quantity" type="number" value={typeAttributes.value} onchange={handleQuantityChange} variant="label-hidden" class="slds-input" data-id={typeAttributes.recid} data-field="Quantity_one__c">
        </lightning-input>
</template>

accountDatatable.js
Update the handleChange method to capture the row ID and field name:
handleChange(event) {
        const rowId = event.target.dataset.id;
        const fieldName = event.target.dataset.field;
        const value = event.detail.value;

        console.log('Row ID:', rowId);
        console.log('Field Name:', fieldName);
        console.log('Value:', value);
}

Update:
I have tried it on my org and the below code is working as expected.
I have referred to this document: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/data-table-custom-types-events.html
First, I have created one component for the input.
CustomInput
   ├──CustomInput.html
   ├──CustomInput.js
   └──CustomInput.js-meta.xml

CustomInput.html
<template>
    <lightning-input type={inputType} value={value} label={label} variant="label-hidden" class="slds-input"
        onchange={handleChange}>
    </lightning-input>
</template>

CustomInput.js
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';

export default class CustomInput extends LightningElement {

    @api inputType;
    @api value;
    @api label;
    @api recordId;
    @api fieldName;

    handleChange(event) {
    const newValue = event.target.value;

    const inputChange = new CustomEvent('inputchange', {
        composed: true,
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true,
        detail: {
            value: newValue,
            recordId: this.recordId,
            fieldName: this.fieldName,
        },
    });
    this.dispatchEvent(inputChange);
    }
}

CustomInput.js-meta.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>61.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
</LightningComponentBundle>

After that, I created the custom-type component.
CustomTypeGlobal
   ├──customInputs.html
   ├──CustomTypeGlobal.js
   └──CustomTypeGlobal.js-meta.xml

customInputs.html
<template>
    <c-custom-input input-type={typeAttributes.inputType} value={typeAttributes.value} label={typeAttributes.label}
        record-id={typeAttributes.recordId} field-name={typeAttributes.fieldName}>
    </c-custom-input>
</template>

CustomTypeGlobal.js
import LightningDatatable from 'lightning/datatable';
import customInputs from './customInputs.html'

export default class CustomTypeGlobal extends LightningDatatable {

    static customTypes = {
        customInput: {
            template: customInputs,
            standardCellLayout: true,
            typeAttributes: ['inputType', 'value', 'label', 'recordId', 'fieldName'],
        },
    };
}

CustomTypeGlobal.js-meta.xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>60.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
</LightningComponentBundle>

After that, I created the custom data table component.
CustomDataTypeTest
   ├──CustomDataTypeTest.html
   ├──CustomDataTypeTest.js
   └──CustomDataTypeTest.js-meta.xml

CustomDataTypeTest.html
<template>
    <!--Test NEW-->
    <lightning-card title="Account List">   
        <c-custom-type-global key-field="Id" data={new_data} columns={new_columns} hide-checkbox-column="true"
            oncellchange={handleCellChange} draft-values={draftValues} oninputchange={handleChange} >
        </c-custom-type-global>
    </lightning-card>
    <lightning-button label="Save" onclick={handleSave} class="slds-m-top_medium">
    </lightning-button>
    <!--End-->
</template>

CustomDataTypeTest.js
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';
import getAccounts from '@salesforce/apex/AccountController.getAccounts';
const test_columns = [
    { label: 'Account Name', fieldName: 'Name' },
    { label: 'Phone', fieldName: 'Phone' },
    { label: 'Industry', fieldName: 'Industry' },
    {
        label: 'Quantity', 
        hideDefaultActions: true, 
        type: 'customInput',
        typeAttributes: {
            inputType: 'number',
            value: { fieldName: 't561258__Test_Number__c' },
            label: 'Quantity',
            recordId: { fieldName: 'Id' },
            fieldName: 't561258__Test_Number__c',
        },
    },
    {
        label: 'Email', 
        hideDefaultActions: true, 
        type: 'customInput',
        typeAttributes: {
            inputType: 'email',
            value: { fieldName: 't561258__Email__c' },
            label: 'Email',
            recordId: { fieldName: 'Id' },
            fieldName: 't561258__Email__c',
        },
    },
    {
        label: 'Phone', 
        hideDefaultActions: true, 
        type: 'customInput',
        typeAttributes: {
            inputType: 'phone',
            value: { fieldName: 'Phone' },
            label: 'Phone',
            recordId: { fieldName: 'Id' },
            fieldName: 'Phone',
        },
    },
    { label: 'Price', fieldName: 'AnnualRevenue', editable: true },
];


export default class CustomDataTypeTest extends LightningElement {
    //test
    @track new_data = [];
    @track new_error;
    new_columns = test_columns;
    connectedCallback() {
        this.fetchAccounts();
    }

    fetchAccounts() {
        getAccounts()
            .then(result => {
                this.new_data = result;
                this.new_error = undefined;
                console.log(' this.data -->' + JSON.stringify(this.new_data));
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.new_error = error;
                this.new_data = undefined;
            });
    }

    handleCellChange(event) {
        console.log('New Test handleCellChange -->' + event.detail);       
    }

    handleSave() {
        // Collect the draft values from the datatable
        const draftValues = this.template.querySelector('lightning-datatable').draftValues;
        if (draftValues.length > 0) {
        }
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        const { recordId, value, fieldName } = event.detail;
        console.log('details:: '+ JSON.stringify(event.detail));
        console.log('const recordId:', recordId);
        console.log('const value:', value);
        console.log('const fieldName:', fieldName);
    }

}

CustomDataTypeTest.js-meta.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <apiVersion>61.0</apiVersion>
    <isExposed>true</isExposed>
    <targets>
        <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
        <target>lightning__AppPage</target>
        <target>lightning__HomePage</target>
        <target>lightning__Tab</target>
    </targets>
</LightningComponentBundle>

Apex Class:
public class AccountController {    
    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<Account> getAccounts() {
        return [SELECT Id, Name, t561258__Email__c, Phone, Industry, t561258__Test_Number__c, AnnualRevenue FROM Account LIMIT 2000];
    }
}

Output::

Note: I have used my org field in this example. You need to change the field name as per your org.

Getting undefined  on rowid and fieldName

@SK2889, In the accountDatatable.js, make sure that you have given the type as your custom type name in column. ex. {         label: 'Quantity', hideDefaultActions: true, type: 'customInput',         typeAttributes: {             value: { fieldName: 'Quantity_one__c' },             recid: { fieldName: 'Id' },             methodquantity: { fieldName: 'methodquantity' }         } }

You can refer to this: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/lwc/guide/data-table-custom-types.html
Here given the example.

Yes i have given custom type name as "type: 'quantityInput'"

@SK2889, I have tried your code in my org and based on that I have made some changes to the code. see the update section of my answer.

Can we do this in generic way, For now it's quantity filed, in future need to add two more column like email and Phone , in this case do we need to create new component like Custominputphone customInputEmail

@SK2889, Yes, you can create a more generic solution to handle different types of inputs. You do not need to create a every time new component. I have updated the code to accept a dynamic type of input.
